# Unable to install jupyter Scheduler on vertex ai user managed notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, scheduler, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to schedule my user managed vertex ai jupyter notebook using jupyter scheduler extension, whenever I try to install it, I get a build error 524. I know that managed notebooks allow scheduling but this extension should also do the same, I remember last week seeing it active for one day and it disappeared later, maybe google removed it.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and help,
I found that you have to install jupyter-scheduler via terminal

```
pip install jupyter_scheduler
```

then install the jupyter scheduler from the extension manager and enable it or run the below command in terminal to enable it

```
jupyter server extension enable --user --py jupyter_scheduler
```

after this save your files and close the page.

Stop the notebook and start it again, after it starts, you can open it to see the jupyter scheduler icon on top of your ipynb file.